# How to Clear byte buffer in android

Tags: android, bytebuffer

I am doing an application that consists of a sending an receiving data from android to the micro controller here in the receiving side that was from micro-controller to the android i was using a byte buffer to store the data.But here i got a problem i want to receive data of multiple bytes at different stages for this i want to clear the byte buffer and re-use the same byte buffer again can any one tell me how to clear the byte buffer

This is my receiving code:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(64);
         byte[] length = buffer.array();
         byte[] Recevied_Data = new byte[64];
         UsbRequest request = new UsbRequest();

         while (true) 
         {
            request.initialize(UsbDriver.USB_Device_Connection, UsbDriver.Data_In_End_Point); 
            request.queue(buffer, 64);
             if (UsbDriver.USB_Device_Connection.requestWait() == request) 
             {
                for(int i=0;i<length.length;i++)
                {   
                    Recevied_Data[i]=buffer.get(i);
                    if(Recevied_Data[0]==0x02 && Recevied_Data[1]==0x3B && Recevied_Data[2]==0x3B && Recevied_Data[3]==0x00 && Recevied_Data[4]==0x03){
                    Communication_Ok=true;
                //  **I want to clear the Buffer Here**           


                }
             }

             }
         }
```

Comment: please try to read the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8462200/examples-of-forcing-freeing-of-native-memory-direct-bytebuffer-has-allocated-us amay be helpful to you.

Comment: did you try: buffer.clear() ?

Comment: But here i am assigning byte buffer to the Received_data[i] i didn't use that dude @TheTanic

Comment: Can you mark in your code where do you want to clear the buffer?

Comment: I want to clear after communication_ok=true flag i edited it please check it

Comment: so when i am understanding you wright, you want to clear the complete buffer? If yes there should be no problem to use buffer.clear(). If you just want to clear a single byte of the buffer, i don´t think that this is possible

Comment: yes Dude i want to clear the complete buffer and reuse it dude @TheTanic

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80636/discussion-between-thetanic-and-deepu).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to erase the data ? Is it local variable ? If it is local variable any way it will be cleared by GC otherwise(in case of member variable) just assign null to buffer. You can do memset by copying 0(using arraycopy) to bytebuffer but it will be pointless code.

Answer (score -2):

[This might be enough.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#clear())
BUT if you want to erase the data completely, you could [Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507963/clearing-a-bytebuffer/14937929#14937929),though it's dirty but simple and readble.